# SQL query to show a portion of string value from a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I wrote a sql query to show the average student attendance from AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE column in CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS table with the following query

```
select AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS
```

[image]

Here the values of AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE are with "%" sign. But if i want to calculate the min or max value then i have to convert the varchar to float. So i need to remove the "%" sign. But i don't want to update the table column. It is possible to show only the values without updating the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace (columnnames, '%', '')